# Get Key from Object - Angular 7

Tags: html, angular

I have this object:

```
this.item =  {
 name:"Michael",
 age:18
};
```

I want to put on HTML

name: Michael
age: 18

```
  <div >{{ item (name) }}</div> --???  should put name
    <div>{{ item.name }}</div>
    <div ">{{item (age)}}</div> --?? should put age
    <div>{{ item.age}}</div>
```

How can I get the string name and age from the object?

Comment: I'd suggest running through [the tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial), which covers this. It's unclear why you think `item (name)` *"should put name"*.

Comment: I dont know how to do it... It was just a manner to explain my problem

Comment: But it seems you do know how to do it, because the next line uses the correct syntax.

Comment: no, the next line I´m printing Michael. I want to print name and age

Comment: Oh, you mean literally "name". Well why do you need interpolation at all, then? Just write e.g. `<div>name</div>`.

Comment: Because If I wanted to refrator age for example I will have to do on both sides

Comment: *Refactor*? You'd have to change it in two places with what you're currently trying to write, too. Unless you have the key `"name"` as a variable, then you can use that to access the property of that name exactly as you would in regular JS.

Comment: Simply write a function that returns `Object.entries`

Answer (score 2):

Use [keyValue](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) pipe

```
<div *ngFor="let item of item | keyvalue">
      {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
</div>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eq9tc7)

---

You should avoid calling a function (which some suggest in comments) inside template. If you do that, that function will be called every time change detection runs. Which is bad. Almost always prefer pipes over method call inside the template.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
<div *ngFor="let key of item">
 <div>{{key}}: {{item[key]}}</div>
</div>
```